# Anaconda can not import some of its default packages

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I downloaded and installed Anaconda through the Mac OSX 64-bit graphical installer (Anaconda2-4.0.0-MacOSX-x86_64.pkg) to a custom directory in my user space. The installer added the default environment setup to my .bash_profile script:

```
# added by Anaconda2 4.0.0 installer
export PATH="/Users/kocevski/bin/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

After the install was complete, I checked the list of available packages with conda...

```
Tachyon> conda list
# packages in environment at /Users/kocevski/bin/anaconda:
#
alabaster                 0.7.7                    py27_0  
anaconda                  4.0.0               np110py27_0  
anaconda-client           1.4.0                    py27_0  
anaconda-navigator        1.1.0                    py27_0  
appnope                   0.1.0                    py27_0  
appscript                 1.0.1                    py27_0  
argcomplete               1.0.0                    py27_1  
astropy                   1.1.2               np110py27_0  
babel                     2.2.0                    py27_0  
backports-abc             0.4                       <pip>
backports.ssl-match-hostname 3.4.0.2                   <pip>
backports_abc             0.4                      py27_0  
beautifulsoup4            4.4.1                    py27_0
...
```

You get the idea.  Now, if I fire up ipython, some of these packages are accessible, while others are not. For example:

```
Tachyon> which ipython
/Users/kocevski/bin/anaconda/bin/ipython

Tachyon> ipython
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

IPython 4.1.2 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
?         -> Introduction and overview of IPython's features.
%quickref -> Quick reference.
help      -> Python's own help system.
object?   -> Details about 'object', use 'object??' for extra details.

In [1]: import babel

In [2]: import beautifulsoup4
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-7e3d2e2a3c50> in <module>()
----> 1 import beautifulsoup4

ImportError: No module named beautifulsoup4
```

Does anyone know why some of the default packages would be accessible, while others are not?  It seems that this is basic as it gets and should work out of the box.

-Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use BeautifulSoup you should import it like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

According to the documentation [here](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

In general, if you are uncertain about the module names, you can check the site-packages of your conda python installation. For your installation it should be `/Users/kocevski/lib/python2.7/site-packages/`. Those are the modules/packages for which you can do `import` on.  The conda package names (what you see when you do `conda list`) are not necessarily the python module names that you want to use when you are doing an import.

Comment: Thank you.  That's exactly what I needed to know.